# interpreting wording of probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two dice are rolled, and the sum of the face values is six. What is the probability that at least one ofnthe dice came up a three?

I want to make sure that I am interpreting the language right when it comes to a question of this sort. So I have been given that the sum of the dice is six. Now working with conditional probabilities, this would mean my sample space has been reduced to all of the possible ways in which six can be obtained from two dice, which is 5 ways. But now it is asking the probability that at least one of the dice came up as three.  Well to get six in total, if one dice came up three then the other woukd have to come up as three so there is only one way that can occur. Thus, the probability of this is $1/5$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your interpretation of the problem is correct, as is your solution.

Comment: I agree with in depth questions, but how is one to progress correctly to in depth questions if one's thinking is flawed before he arrives there? Then you are doing yourself a disservice.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and I agree.  Still, In my opinion this question may have been better phrased by adding something along the lines of 'what tips do users have for understanding [conditional(?)] probability questions in general.'  Just my opinion.

Comment: I actually agree with that rephrasing, it does give the question a greater use. I will see if there is a question like that already answered as i assume there is, but if there isn't then i'll ask it. Cheers for the suggestion.

Comment: Some of us choose to use our 30 characters for positive encouragement. Others choose to reiterate the main point. But some folks choose instead to be passive-aggressive, and to criticize OP's question to boot.

Comment: Fair enough.  This wasn't my best answer.  I think the previous comments describe what I was getting at.  Also @dc3rd if you find such a question, please let me know as I am always interested in the subject.